# Prevent triggering next activity if no files were copied in previous activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I am using **Azure Data Factory** to copy the data from one **Blob Storage Account** to **Data Lake Storage Gen2** account.

I have created a pipeline and created a copy activity inside that. I trigger this pipeline from a Timer Trigger Azure Function using C# SDK.

I am copying only incremental data by making use of **Filter by last modified** feature. I am passing UTC StartTime and EndTime.

Now, the question is - I don't want to trigger the second activity if no files are found within this range. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use If Condition activity, and check whether has files through this expression:    `@greater(activity('Copy data1').output.filesWritten,0)`. Then put the second activity into case True activity like this:

[image]